# Create a folder by date then rename a file with prior date prefix then move file by extension into folder

Tags: powershell

This is my first time posting so I apologize if the formatting is unclear or incorrect. I'll try my best to have things look better as I go.
I am trying to create a power shell script that will create a folder with the year and prior month.
I then want to move a certain ext or files only into the folder that was created.

My issue right now is that any text file inside Temp or Temp\files will be moved into the folder that gets created.
On top of that the files that were moved already once would move again the following month and the information in the prior folder will be gone.
Is there any way I can have it just move the files that are outside the folder into the new folder?
My other issue now is I would like to create the same date format as a prefix to the text document example: 201902-_Name.txt

I haven't figured out the 2nd part and I kinda sorta figured out the 1st part except for it grabs anything inside temp and moves it to the new folder it creates.

```
# Get the files which should be moved, without folders
$files = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Temp\' -Recurse | where {!$_.PsIsContainer}

# List Files which will be moved
$files

# Target Folder where files should be moved to. The script will automatically create a folder for the year and month.
$targetPath = 'C:\Temp\files\'

foreach ($file in $files){
    # Get year and Month of the file
    # I used LastWriteTime since this are synced files and the creation day will be the date when it was synced
    $year = $file.LastWriteTime.Year.ToString()
    $month = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).ToString('MM')
    $monthname = (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName($month)

    # Out FileName, year and month
    $file.Name
    $year
    $month
    $monthname

    # Set Directory Path
    $Directory = $targetPath + "\" + $year + $month

    # Create directory if it doesn't exsist
    if (!(Test-Path $Directory)){
        New-Item $directory -type directory
    }

    # Move File to new location
    $file | Move-Item -Destination $Directory
}
```

Comment: do you really want to use `-Recurse` on the source directory tree? if you leave that out, you will not have the problem of previous dirs/files being changed.

Comment: You state `# Get year and Month of the file` but you only get the year from the file and take the previous month from current date?

Answer (score 1):

The by far easiest way to tackle your problem #1 is to have the files moved to a target folder that is **NOT** inside the source folder.

If that is not what you want, then you need to add an extra test for the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to filter out any files that are in the target folder.

Something like this should work:

```
$sourcePath = 'C:\Temp\'        #'# The folder in which the files to move are
$targetPath = 'C:\Temp\files\'  #'# The folder where the files should be moved to

# Get the files which should be moved, without folders and exclude any file that is in the target folder
$files = Get-ChildItem $sourcePath -File -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.FullName -notlike "$targetPath*" }
# for PowerShell version below 3.0 use this:
# $files = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Temp\' -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer -and $_.FullName -notlike "$targetPath*"}

# List Files which will be moved
# $files

foreach ($file in $files){
    # Get year and Month of the file
    # I used LastWriteTime since this are synced files and the creation day will be the date when it was synced
    $year      = $file.LastWriteTime.Year
    $month     = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).ToString('MM')             # last month from current date
    $monthname = (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName($month)

    # Out FileName, year and month
    # $file.Name
    # $year
    # $month
    # $monthname

    $dateString = '{0}{1}' -f $year, $month
    # Set Directory Path
    $Directory = Join-Path -Path $targetPath -ChildPath $dateString

    # Create directory if it doesn't exsist
    if (!(Test-Path $Directory -PathType Container)){
        New-Item $Directory -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
    }

    # Move File to new location and prepend the date prefix to its name
    $targetFile = Join-Path -Path $Directory -ChildPath ('{0}-{1}' -f $dateString, $file.Name)
    $file | Move-Item -Destination $targetFile -Force
}
```

As you can see, by using the same $dateString variable, the `Move-Item` cmdlet not only moves, but renames the files aswell.

Hope this helps