# Moving folders in a directory

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a powershell script which allows me to move all folders from a directory with a filter to exclude something. But the issue is to when trying to move the folders, the content inside them is moved and the folder is deleted instead of the whole folder moving.

The Script

```
[string] $currentDir = $PSScriptRoot
[string] $newDir = $currentDir + '\moveFolder'

# I have tried both of these but the result is still the same
Get-ChildItem -Path $currentDir -Directory | Where-Object { $_.FullName -notmatch 'moveFolder'} | Move-Item -Destination ($newDir + '\build')
Move-Item -Path ($currentDir + '\*') -Destination ($newDir + '\build') -Exclude moveFolder
```

Example of what happens

Before

```
- Main Folder
    - Subfolder1
       - abc
       - abcd.txt
    - moveFolder
```

After

```
- Main Folder
   - moveFolder
      - abc
      - abcd.txt
```

Like you see the contents of the folder were moved instead of the whole folder moving over. It works when I try it in a powershell window, but when running from a script file this happens.

Comment: i **_think_** the part of the file name used by `Move-Item` in a pipeline is the `.Name`. that would mean the folder structure would be lost. you likely need to build the FULL new file name for the destination to get the source dir to move. i have not tested this, tho. [*blush*]

Comment: Would you be able to define the "build the full new file name", I'm still relatively new to powershell

Comment: one way would be to replace the path in $FileToMove.FullName` with your destination path.

Comment: You need to make sure the destination path exists before you try to move anything in there. If the destination does not exist, create it first. Looks rather similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55172373/create-a-folder-by-date-then-rename-a-file-with-prior-date-prefix-then-move-file/55179836#55179836)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I forgot to create the "build" folder. I created the "moveFolder" but totally forgot about that.

The end result is as follows

```
[string] $currentDir = $PSScriptRoot
[string] $newDir = $currentDir + '\moveFolder'
[string] $destination = $newDir + '\build\'
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $destination
Get-ChildItem -Path $currentDir -Directory -Exclude moveFolder | Move-Item -Destination $destination
```